# Ubuntu 16.04 graphics resolution problem

Tags: 16.04, graphics, display-resolution, nouveau

I have an nvdia graphics card. 
I had installed ubuntu 16.04 with its default graphics driver nouveau. Even though there was no need, i tried changing it to Nvdia driver and got issues. 
So i tried changing back to nouveau. 
Now, nouveau seems to have issues with resolution. It shows 1024x768 but the display seems stretched and weird. 
I dont know which resolution it was before.